# I want to disable the shadow effect on a specific aero window

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi, aero, hwnd

I want to disable the shadow effect on a specific aero window. All I have is the HWND of this window, is this possible?

Comment: What language do you want to use? C#, VB.Net, C++, etc?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Does not really matter; the Windows API looks the same from any language.

Comment: I wanted to know so I could provide a code example without the need for the asker to translate it.

Comment: Yes it doesn't matter because its the winapi. C# would be good

Comment: @Don- Thanks, I think there is a function to do this

Comment: I could not find a function to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow is defined by the theme currently used by the OS. You cannot disable it for one window only. You can change the theme and disable shadows, but it will be a system-wide  change, not specific to one window.

In your case, one of the best approached would be creating your own window structure (starting from a borderless window) that will have similar transparency properties as Aero. This will not be an easy task, but certainly achievable.

Comment: The problem is I want to disable the shadow on a 3rd party app

Comment: That's going to be a system-wide change that will affect all applications. That's the way the composition engine works.