# WPF Aero window without shadow

Tags: wpf, aero, blur, shadow, dwm

I am aware of the following question:
[I want to disable the shadow effect on a specific aero window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696838/i-want-to-disable-the-shadow-effect-on-a-specific-aero-window)

However, I still need the DWM blur/reflections behind my Aero window, so I can't create a custom transparent one. How would I approach that? I could handle the reflections by myself, but I don't know how to create a blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it using DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow. :)